# Itextsharp Pdf with password and watermark protected

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

Is there any function in Itextsharp whether pdf has password or watermark.

I have written below code but Contains("Downloaded By") will be dynamic every time.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FilePassword);
int page1;

if (FilePassword.Equals(""))
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(CurrentPath, bytes);
    countWaterMarkFound = 0;
    // Calculate whether watermark exist in the pdf 
    for (page1 = 1; page1 <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page1++)
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page1, strategy);
        if (currentPageText.Contains("Downloaded By"))
        {
            countWaterMarkFound++;
            // adding new WaterMark here 
        }
    }
    pdfReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: A watermark is not necessarily marked as such in a PDF, you won't get a certain check for it.

Comment: thanks @mkl. Is there any check whether pdf is Password protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Watermarks

A watermark is not necessarily marked as such in a PDF, you won't get a certain check for it.

#### Passwords

First of all, there are types of passwords in PDFs:

- the *user password* and
- the *owner password*.

If a PDF is encrypted and you open it with the *owner password*, you have full access to the PDF in PDF processors. If you merely open it with the *user password*, the PDF processor may limit your access according to the PDF specification.

There is a default password value given in the PDF specification. If a PDF is encrypted with that password as user password, you can usually open it without entering a password at all or entering the empty string as password.

If the user password is not the default password, you need to enter a password to open the PDF.

Thus,

- if you cannot open a PDF using `new PdfReader(CurrentPath)`, it is encrypted; in particular it is protected with a non-default user password (or a certificate);
- if you can open it using `pdfReader = new PdfReader(CurrentPath)`, check `pdfReader.isEncrypted()`; if that returns `true`, the PDF is encrypted using the default user password; otherwise it is not encrypted.